# Bug with -= and web workers

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm developing a little game in JS and I'm using many web workers to manage my enemies. 
Here is my `ennemis.js` code (it's my web worker):

```
var xEnnemis, nbrEnnemis;
var x=0;
//Seul objectif : calculer les positions des ennemis.
onmessage = function(e) {
    var idEnnemis = String(e.data[0]);
    var recXEnn = String(e.data[1]);




    xEnnemis = recXEnn;
    var recSpeedEnn = String(e.data[2]);
    vitesseEnnemis = recSpeedEnn;

    animationEnnemisInterval = setInterval(calculateEnnemisPos, 120); //60

    function calculateEnnemisPos(){
            if (xEnnemis>0){
                xEnnemis -= vitesseEnnemis;
            }else{
                xEnnemis=0;
            }
        //console.log("Send datas + "+ idEnnemis);
        postMessage([idEnnemis, xEnnemis]);
    } 
}
```

And here is my main script

```
if (typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {console.log("Tu supportes les workers  !")} else {console.log("Sorry bro...");} 
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//ENEMIE
var nbrnnemis = 3; //Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 5 + 1) ) + 5;
var ennemie = new Image();
ennemie.src = "media/zombie.png";
var xEnnemisGen = [];
var vitesseEnnemis = [];
var posEnnemisrecue = [];
var ennemisRecu = 0;
var animZombie=0;
for (i=0;i<nbrEnnemis; i++){
    var w = new Worker('ennemis.js');
    xEnnemisGen[i] = 500;
    //xEnnemisGen[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1401 - 1290 + 1) ) + 1281;
    vitesseEnnemis[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 10 + 1) ) + 4;
    //console.log("Envoyé au worker : " +i + " " + xEnnemisGen[i] + " " + vitesseEnnemis[i] );
    w.onmessage = test;
    w.postMessage([i, xEnnemisGen[i], vitesseEnnemis[i]]);
}
console.log("Nombres d'ennemis : " + nbrEnnemis);
//console.log(xEnnemis);
function test(e){
    var id = String(e.data[0]);
    var position = String(e.data[1]);
    //console.log("Just received "+e.data+ " from Worker !"); //fait ramer de ouf
    console.log("Recu la position: "+position+" avec l'id: " +id);
    posEnnemisrecue.push(position);
    ennemisRecu++;
    if (ennemisRecu == nbrEnnemis){
        if (animZombie==23){animZombie=0;}else{animZombie+=1;}
        for (i=0;i<nbrEnnemis;i++){
            ctx.drawImage(ennemie, animZombie*118,0, 118,177, posEnnemisrecue[i], 500, 118,177);
            console.log("c'est dessiné + "+ posEnnemisrecue[i]);
        }
        posEnnemisrecue=[];
        ennemisRecu = 0;
        //ctx.clearRect(0,0,1280, 720);
        ctx.drawImage(ennemie, animZombie*118,0, 118,177, 0, 0, 118,177);
        console.log(animZombie);
        console.log("dessiné " + animZombie);
    }
}
```

But sometimes the value of `xEnnemis` sent by my web worker does not decrease; it even increases as we can see on this log:

```
dessiné 6
Recu la position: 500 avec l'id: 2
Recu la position: 0 avec l'id: 1
Recu la position: 0 avec l'id: 0
c'est dessiné + 500
c'est dessiné + 0
7
dessiné 7
Recu la position: 500 avec l'id: 2
Recu la position: 0 avec l'id: 1
Recu la position: 0 avec l'id: 0
c'est dessiné + 500
c'est dessiné + 0
```

Do you have any idea of why ?
Thanks !

**Edit: May the fourth, after test of the C.Champagne version**

Okay, just tested, seems not to work. The string wasn't the answer. Thanks anyway for your help !

The new Log:

```
dessiné 15
Recu la position: 0 avec l'id: 0
Recu la position: 2100 avec l'id: 1
Recu la position: 0 avec l'id: 2
c'est dessiné + 0
c'est dessiné + 2100
c'est dessiné + 0
16
dessiné 16
Recu la position: 0 avec l'id: 0
Recu la position: 2101 avec l'id: 1
Recu la position: 0 avec l'id: 2
c'est dessiné + 0
c'est dessiné + 2101
c'est dessiné + 0
17
dessiné 17
Recu la position: 0 avec l'id: 0
Recu la position: 2102 avec l'id: 1
Recu la position: 0 avec l'id: 2
c'est dessiné + 0
c'est dessiné + 2102
c'est dessiné + 0
18
```

As you can see, it's even increasing.
I wonder if it's not the fault of my `test(e)` function of my main script, which is called too many times at once and does anything.

Just tested it on Chrome, to see if it was not a navigator error, and it's doing the same. If you have any idea, because I'm stuck.
Thanks in advance !

**Edit: 7 May 2018**

Okay guys, just found out ! it's because

```
vitesseEnnemis[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 10 + 1) ) + 4;
```

returns sometimes wrong values ! I don't know why, but here are some results

```
Array [ -1, 0, -1 ]
```

As you can see, I will continue my investigation.
If you ever had the same problem, please comment this post !

Thanks in advance !

Escatrag

Comment: "using many web workers to manage my enemies"  - I don't think this is a good idea. Why can't you put them in the same main script?

Comment: What do you expect, doing `-=` on strings?

Comment: Just a side remark for readability : you should not write your `if`...`else` on the same line. In addition to that, you test if workers are supported. Why don't you exit if it not he case?

Comment: @RaphaMex: i expect it to subtract using math: `x="55";x-=3;alert(x);// shows 52` because only the `+` operator is type ambiguous.

Comment: @Dai because i don't know how many ennemis will appears, and i don't want my main thread be busy by compute their position

Comment: @RaphaMex no, just send their positions. I think ennemis.js is bugged, but i don't find where

Comment: @Estragad sorry to not have written an answer before. I needed some more time

Comment: @C.Champagne no problem, i have no time limit ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooooo, after looking more precisely about this line

```
vitesseEnnemis[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 10 + 1) ) + 4;
```

I decided to check if the syntax was correct. The MDN [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) here spells the correct syntax. Instead of my line, my code should be

```
vitesseEnnemis[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 + 1) ) + 1;
```

Everything is now running fine, I pass the question as solved.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

As I (and others) suspected, your use of strings instead of numbers seems to make problem.

It is a bad idea to make calculations with strings and you can get rather unexpected behaviour (concatenation instead of addition...).

I changed the folling initializations in the Worker

```
var idEnnemis = String(e.data[0]);
var recXEnn = String(e.data[1]);

xEnnemis = recXEnn;
var recSpeedEnn = String(e.data[2]);
```

...by

```
var idEnnemis = e.data[0];
var recXEnn = e.data[1];

xEnnemis = recXEnn;
var recSpeedEnn = e.data[2];
```

...and things seem to get better.

Comment: Sorry, was a bit busy. Well, I've just tested it, and it seems to keep doing the error. Don't know why.

Comment: I just edited my question with the result of the new log, if you want you can have a look ! Thanks for the time you spent on it !